Is there a faster way to achieve this web scrape without selenium?
I have a piece of code in Python to input a piece of English text into a website (https://edu.visl.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/trees.php), and extract the syntactic tree drawn from it. So far, I have been doing this in selenium as follows:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        service = Service(executable_path="c:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    
        driver.get("https://edu.visl.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/trees.php")
        form = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "theform")
        dropdown = form.find_element(By.NAME, "visual")
        drop = Select(dropdown)
        drop.select_by_visible_text("Vertical")
        search = form.find_element(By.NAME, "text")
        search.send_keys("John killed the cat with a hammer.")
        submit = form.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
        submit.click()
        results = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "pre")
        soup = str(bs(results.get_attribute("innerHTML"), "html.parser"))

However, I need to do this over and over again (in a loop), which is way too slow for my purposes. Is there a faster way to do this?

HTMLUnit will be faster.  You could also switch over to native requests... (i.e. Curl or just python's requests...) It's worth a check to see if they have a public API you can use.  (and tell John to leave the cats alone!)

Use requests instead:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    'text': 'John killed the cat with a hammer.',
    'export': 'Export and Download',
    'parser': 'tree',
    'visual': 'vertical',
    'symbol': 'default',
}

url = 'https://edu.visl.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/trees.php'
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
result = soup.body.pre.get_text(strip=True)

print(result)

